# Data binding through UserControl

Tags: xaml, uwp, user-controls, winrt-xaml

Here's a minimal example of data binding. I would like know how to factor out both the `ToggleSwitch` and `Button` into different `UserControl`s while keeping the data binding.

```xml
//MainWindow.xaml
<StackPanel>
    <ToggleSwitch x:Name="MyToggle" OffContent="Off" OnContent="On"/>
    <Button IsEnabled="{x:Bind MyToggle.IsOn, Mode=OneWay}" Content="Click Me"/>
</StackPanel>

// MainWindow.idl
Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls.ToggleSwitch MyToggle{ get; };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Publically expose MyToggleControl and MyToggle so `"{x:Bind MyToggleControl.MyToggle.IsOn}"` is available. Then create `IsButtonEnabled` property so that `IsButtonEnabled="{x:Bind ...}"` will work.

---

Expose the `UserControlToggle` as a public property of `MainWindow`

```xml
// MainWindow.xaml
<StackPanel>
    <local:UserControlToggle x:Name="MyToggleControl" x:FieldModifier="public"/>
    <local:UserControlButton IsButtonEnabled="{x:Bind MyToggleControl.MyToggle.IsOn, Mode=OneWay}"/>
</StackPanel>

// MainWindow.idl needed for cppwinrt as x:FieldModifier doesn't work
import "UserControlToggle.idl";
UserControlToggle MyToggleControl{ get; };
```

Expose the `ToggleSwitch` as a public property of `UserControlToggle`

```xml
// UserControlToggle.xaml
<ToggleSwitch x:Name="MyToggle" x:FieldModifier="public" OffContent="Off" OnContent="On"/>

// UserControlToggle.idl
Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls.ToggleSwitch MyToggle{ get; };
```

---

Wrap the buttons `IsEnabled` property to a property on `UserControlButton`

```cpp
// UserControlButton.xaml
<Button x:Name="myButton" Click="myButton_Click">Enable/Disable</Button>

// UserControlButton.idl
Boolean IsButtonEnabled;

// UserControlButton.xaml.cpp
bool UserControl::IsButtonEnabled()
{
    return myButton().IsEnabled();
}

void UserControl::IsButtonEnabled(bool value)
{
    myButton().IsEnabled(value);
}
```